# how to get the value from specific nested class with xpath

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-crawler

im trying to get the value of the class "sum_num" with xpath .i have 4 classes witrh the same name

when i'm running the code, i'm getting the value '0' or the value for the 3rd class, which is the span text - "lblPrice1"

the class "sum_num" is exsiting 4 times in the pages
but i need only the value or the 2nd one.

how to get only the 2nd value from the class "sum_num" " ?
and more - is this the best way to crawl a web page ?

python  (i have tried both option):

```
cost = product_link_selector.xpath('//div[./div/@class="product_code_price"]div/div/div/@class = sum_num/text()').get()

cost = product_link_selector.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"item_sum_group product compare_main")]//*[contains(@class, "sum_num")]').get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index to get the 2nd item. Here is the sample code for using the index.

```
(//*[@attribute='attribute_value')[index]
```

Try with the below.

```
product_link_selector.xpath('(//*[contains(@class,"item_sum_group product compare_main")]//*[contains(@class, "sum_num")])[2]').get()
```

Comment: can provide the simplified solution if you can share the html of the `item_sum_group product compare_main` element with children.

Comment: i think i can't see the class because the login has failed  - i'm getting status 200 but actually, im not logged in